# "Incorrect syntax near '='" runtime error c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

command.CommandText = 
   "INSERT INTO [Users] 
    VALUES (Username=@username, Firstname=@firstname
          , Lastname=@lastname, ProfilePic=NULL, Bio=@bio, Email=@email
          , EmailIsVerified=@emailverified, Hash=@hash, CompanyID=@companyid)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", m_username);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", m_firstname);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", m_lastname);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bio", m_bio);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", m_email);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailverified", (m_emailIsVerified ? "yes" : "no"));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash", m_hash);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyid", m_companyID);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Connection = sqlConnection;

sqlConnection.Open();

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

sqlConnection.Close();
```

With the above code I get the "Syntax error near =" error. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Read up on the insert sql statement. Your syntax is wrong. Just list the parameters in the order they are in the table, don't have the `ColumnName=` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your INSERT statement do not use Username=@username etc, because that is not valid SQL. It should look like this instead:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Users] VALUES (@username, @firstname, @lastname, NULL, @bio, @email, @emailverified, @hash, @companyid)";
```

This assumes the values are in the same order as the columns in the database, otherwise you will need to specify the columns too.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change your INSERT statement's syntax:

```
INSERT INTO [Users] (UserName, FirstName, ...)
SELECT @UserName, @firstname, ...
```

Documentation on the [INSERT syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

It is considered better practice to explicitly list out the columns you will `INSERT INTO`.  This prevents any (potentially difficult to troubleshoot) issues if the column order of your table is modified.  This could cause your `INSERT` to either fail (inserting into invalid types), or insert values into unexpected columns (re-order columns, but they have the same type, so the insert will succeed)